# Estrutura condicional não funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, condição

Várias vezes, principalmente quando o segundo preço é maior que os outros, o programa acusa que ele é o mais barato.

```
#Faça um programa que pergunte o preço de três produtos e informe qual produto 
#você deve comprar, sabendo que a decisão é sempre pelo mais barato.


p1 = input("Digite o 1° preço: ")
p2 = input("Digite o 2° preço: ")
p3 = input("Digite o 3° preço: ")

if p1 < p2 and p1 < p3:
    print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p1}')
elif p2 < p1 and p3:
    print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p2}')
elif p3 < p2 and p3 < p1:
    print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p3}')
else:
    if p1 == p2 and p1 < p3:
        print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p1} e o {p2}')
    elif p1 == p3 and p1 < p2:
        print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p1} e o {p3}')
    elif p2 == p3 and p2 < p1:
        print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p2} e o {p3}')
    elif p1==p2 and p2==p3:
        print('Todos os produtos tem o mesmo valor.')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O maior problema é que não está fazendo uma completa verificação da condição no segundo `if`. Mas o código tem problemas.

Um deles é não estar convertendo para inteiro, então um número como 10 será menor que 2 por exemplo porque considerando *string* estará comprando  inicialmente o primeiro caractere de cada texto, ou seja comparando "1" com "2" e 1 é menor que 2, então já se sabe que aquele texto é menor e nem precisa verificar o resto. Um erro frequente é as pessoas confundirem representação textual de um número com um número de fato. Preferi não tratar o erro de digitação, mas se alguém digitar algo que não seja um número a aplicação quebrará. Isto pode ficar como próximo exercício.

O enunciado não fala nada em tratar o empate de forma diferenciada e faz pouco sentido, e mesmo que faça esta lógica está errada e dá resultado equivocado. Como a lógica é só dizer o mais barato é só tirá-la e sempre dará o resultado esperado. Se realmente quiser insistir nisso precisa de outra lógica, para, inclusive, tratar o empate de dois números apenas.

```
p1 = int(input("Digite o 1° preço: "))
p2 = int(input("Digite o 2° preço: "))
p3 = int(input("Digite o 3° preço: "))
if p1 < p2 and p1 < p3:
    print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p1}')
elif p2 < p1 and p2 < p3:
    print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p2}')
elif p3 < p2 and p3 < p1:
    print(f'O produto mais barato é o {p3}')
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nQlNPZ). E [no **Coding Ground**](https://repl.it/join/olxmobgi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Conditional.py).

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra alternativa para este problema, e também bem mais escalável, é usar as estruturas de dados da própria linguagem para a resolução do problema:

```
ITEMS = 3
precos = []

for item in range(1, ITEMS + 1):   
    precos.append(int(input(f"Preço do {item}º item = ")))

menor_preco = min(precos)

print(f"O produto mais barato é o {menor_preco}")
```

Neste caso o que você faz é receber todos os valores em uma lista e tirar delas o menor valor com a função `min()`. A vantagem desta abordagem, além da já citada escalabilidade pois ele funciona para 3, 30 ou 3000 preços, é que o código é bem mais limpo e legível.